# Повторное выделение памяти (new[])

Tags: c++

Как можно выделить память повторно, но так, чтобы память не текла и остались старые значения?

Написал кусок кода для понимания, но понимаю, что чего-то не хватает:

```
bool exit = false;
int *point, *old_point;

while(!exit){
    cin>>x;

    point = new int[x];
    old_point = new int[x];

    for(int i = 0; i<x; i++){
        if(!point[i])
            cin>>point[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)
        cout<<point[i]<<" ";

    cout<<"\n";
    old_point = point;

    delete[] point;

}
```

Хочу стандартными средствами, про `std::vector` не говорить :)
*Заранее благодарю!*

Comment: Вам нужен массив, который динамически меняет свой размер?

Comment: @pol500 да

Comment: Открою тайну: std::vector - стандартное средство. А теперь скажите мне, зачем изобретать этот велосипед???

Comment: @gecube Чисто для себя. Понять как это работает. "Стандартными средствами" - под этим я имел ввиду, что не хочу использовать для этих целей либы.

Comment: @NameX, насколько помню в С++ есть new и delete, но нет "resize". 

Если не использовать vector, то проще всего сделать на чистом С - посмотрите на malloc/realloc. Это почти наверняка будет эффективнее, чем new/new/copy/delete.

Собственно внутри С++ это делается именно так.

Про if(!point[i]) @Котик Вам уже написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вообще, это, конечно же кошмар:**

```
   old_point = point;
```

Так делать ни в коем случае нельзя, предварительно не поместив указатель на `old_point` в какую-нибудь другую переменную, чтобы потом можно было освободить! Это самая распространенная ошибка: `копирование в указатель указатель`.

[[@Котик](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)](/users/4149/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82_%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), кстати, дал вам хороший совет, что количество **new должно совпадать с количеством вызовов delete**. У вас это правило не соблюдается, потому что производится копирования указателя в указатель. Следствие => память течет...

---

**Вы спрашиваете:**

```
  можно выделить память повторно, но так, чтобы память не текла и остались старые значения.
```

Нет, в C++ так нельзя, если вы имеете работу с примитивами из C. Предположим, это:

```
char *str = new str[5];
str = "01234";
str = new str[6];  // Нет!
cout<<str<<endl;  // "\n"
```

Не приведет к расширению первоначальных рамеров массива символов `str`. Это полностью сотрет все старые значения и заново перераспределит память уже для шести символов типа `char`. Причем, далеко не факт, что память будет выделена в той же области, где прежде...я бы даже сказал, очень врядли.

---

Указатели и без того являются источником проблем для некоторых программистов( в основном, начинающих ), так что использовать их надо очень и очень осторожно.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пользоваться штатными средствами std::vector

Comment: Можно вектором, можно более полноценным контейнером - **deque**, можно **std::list**, если разрешено получать доступ к элементам только в прямой и обратной последовательности( без произвольного доступа )...

Comment: - В вашем коде, кстати говоря, `memory leak` происходит уже в момент `str = "01234";`

- Старые значения никто стирать не будет, а память **не перераспределяется.** Аллокатор просто выделит новый блок памяти, а для старого блока есть сильная гарантия *(не для кастомных аллокаторов, разумеется)*, что значения в нем будут сохранены до завершения приложения.

- В той же самой области память не будет выделена точно - можно привести элементарный контрпример.

- Интересно, с чего вы решили назвать `std::deque` *более полноценным,* нежели `std::vector` :)

Comment: Unterbehälter und überbehälter

Answer (score 5):

- Есть простое правило - количество вызовов `new / new[]` должно совпадать с количеством вызовов `delete / delete[]`.

> *Можете проверить выполнение данного условие для вашего кода :)*

- Утечка памяти происходит из-за наличия в вашем коде строки `old_point = point`.

> - Так происходит по той причине, что в начале программы вы выделяете *два блока памяти*  и связываете с этими блоками два *указателя* - `point` и `new_point`, соответственно.
> - В момент `old_point = point` оба этих указателя начинают указывать на один и тот же блок памяти, соответственно, вы теряете способ обратиться ко второму из этих блоков, тем самым получая утечку памяти, поскольку для него нужно вызвать `delete[]`.

- Если вы хотите сделать копию уже имеющегося и заполненного участка памяти, то самый простой для понимания способ заключается в том, чтобы выделить участок памяти такого же размера и *поэлементно* скопировать в него старые данные.
- В строчке `if(!point[i])` у вас `undefined behavior` - вы пытаетесь обратиться к участку памяти, который может быть заполнен чем угодно.
- Переменная `exit` не используется.

Comment: Хорошо вы все расписали здесь. Кстати, **exit** используется в цикле, только смысла от него чуть меньше чем нифига. Можно было вместо этого просто написать:

     while(true){...}

Answer (score 2):

Попозже напишу код. А пока порекомендую для массивов из POD использовать "ручное" выделение памяти с использованием [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/malloc/) и [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/).

Если же играть с new/delete, то сохраняйте старый указатель, копируйте вручную элементы из староно массива в новый и освобождайте уже ненужную память. Не наоборот. После освобождения памяти указатель недействителен!!!!

Код с new/delete:

```
int *point = NULL, *old_point = NULL;
int num;
int size = 0;
int i;

do{
    cin>>num;

    size++;
    point = new int[size]; // выделяем память

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
      point[i] = old_point[i];

    point[size - 1] = num;    
    if (size>1) delete[] old_point; // удаляем старую копию
    old_point = point;  // старой копией становится текущая, т.е. до момента выделения памяти для point
} while (num!=0);

delete[] point;
```

Comment: @gecube, выделение нового блока, копирование и удаление старого при чтении **каждого** элемента не смущает ?

Наверное, все таки, выделяемую память надо наращивать блоками разумного размера (например по 1000 элементов), а в конце урезать  до актуального size.

Кстати, проверку if(size>1) можно выбросить. В C++ delete безболезненно реагирует на NULL.

Comment: Дык, пример же =) а не руководство к действию =)

Answer (score 0):

Ко всему уже посоветованному можно предложить поизвращаться с placement new - физически выделить достаточно большой кусок, а потом уже в нем выделять кусочки нужного размера (без затирания старых данных)

Comment: Да, если у автора вопросы проблемы с обычными `new[] / delete[]`, то с `placement new`, конечно же, все станет проще.

Answer (score 0):

[@NameX](/users/4118/namex), вот пример динамического массива. Ввод данных безусловно надо делать аккуратнее, но это пример "наращивания" массива и комбинации методов распределения памяти в C и C++.

```
#define INCR 1024
/*
  Возвращает заполненный массив int[], выделенный new
  последний введенный элемент 0
  его размер пишется по адресу retsize
  При ошибке (нет памяти) возвращает NULL 
  и записывает -1 по адресу retsize.
 */
int *
get_int_array(int *retsize)
{
  *retsize = -1;
  int num, size = INCR, cur = 0, *res,
    *arr = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(*arr));
  if (!arr)
    return NULL;
  do {
    cin >> num;
    if (cur > size-1) {
      int *t = (int *)realloc(arr,(size+=INCR)*sizeof(*arr));
      if (!t) {
        free(arr);
        return NULL;
      }
      arr = t;
    }
    arr[cur++] = num;
  } while (num);

  if (*retsize = cur) {
    res =  new int(cur);
    memcpy(res,arr,cur*sizeof(*arr));
  }
  free(arr);
  return res;
}
```

Вызывать:

```
....
int size, *point = get_int_array(&size);
....
delete[] point;
....
```

Примерно в таком духе.